# PCI card reader stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pci

Here's my configuration:

```
sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)

sudo file -s /dev/mmcblk0p1
/dev/mmcblk0p1: DOS/MBR boot sector
```

Every time I try to mount it manually I get the following:

```
sudo mount  /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/vova/
mount: /dev/mmcblk0p1: more filesystems detected. This should not happen,
       use -t <type> to explicitly specify the filesystem type or
       use wipefs(8) to clean up the device.
```

Can anyone help out? I can't figure this out.

Comment: Googling suggests trying some explict filesystem type. Perhaps `mount -t exfat...`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha -- post an official answer and I'll accept it...I've tried a bunch of other filesystem configurations but not 'extfat', and it worked :)

Comment: Done. Does `vfat` not work? That's what I have used in the past.

Comment: vfat doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/vova/
```

as suggested by Google, when encountering similar error messages.
Better still, add a suitable line to `/etc/fstab`. Something like this?

```
UUID="insert uuid here"   /media/vova  exfat    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

You can obtain the UUID by checking for the device's UUID with`blkid` with the device attached to your computer. Doing this saves you from having to check which device file represents your reader.

Automating the mount would be an even better idea. I have used `usbmount` in the past. This may work with `exfat` if you add `exfat` to the following line in your 
`/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`.

```
FILESYSTEMS="vfat ext2 ext3 ext4 hfsplus"
```

which is the default, I think. I have "ntfs" added in mine. Change
from `VERBOSE=no` to `VERBOSE=yes` in `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf` and test by plugging in. Look at `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` for output.